# Select all posts made on the same date

Tags: php, sql

I have a table structure like this:

```
sender| receiver| message|date|time
----------------------------------
```

How do I select all the messages written on the same date, with them appearing at the top, just like Facebook Chat?

I've tried something like this:

```
<?php

            $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
            $db=mysql_select_db ("chat",$con);

             $query=" select * from chat where sender='$send' 
             and   receiver='$rec' order by date";
             $result=mysql_query($query);
            while($r2=mysql_fetch_array($result))
              echo "<div>{$r2['date']}</div>";
             {

                echo"<div>{$r2['message']}</div>";
             }
?>
```

Comment: Do you just want to select the message for a specific date or do you mean

Mar 1
Message
Message
Mar 2
Message
Mar 3

Comment: something like this

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to run an SQL query directly from PHP, which you can't do - you'll need to connect to your database first. Then you need to pass the `$send` and `$rec` variables to your database, preferably through [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

It depends on whether you're using **[MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** or **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** as to exactly how you should do that, but I'll assume you're not using the `mysql_` constructor, as that was [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql).

As such, here's an example of how to do this through MySQLi with prepared statements:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(
"SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE sender = ? && receiver = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $send, $rec); 
// "ss' is a format string, each "s" means string
// Each variable gets passed to the question marks, in order
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($result);
```

You then have the results stored in `$result`, and are free to manipulate from there.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: i remove the the connection string to shorten the code. i am trying to achieve something like facebook chat or whatapp where date are displayed before messages

Comment: The code that you claim to have shortened (and therefor omitted) is the *most* important part; it's critical to know if there's an error there or not. The above code will get the results from the database stored in the `$result` variable. You can then output them to the page with `echo $result->field`, and position them where you want them to appear on the page with CSS.

Comment: there is no error in the code may be what i need is how to position the output using css. i mean something like 2017-11-22 msg1,msg2,msg3

Comment: To position the text with CSS, you'll need to provide your relevant markup (HTML) and all relevant CSS selectors. Assuming you're able to get the output from your database coming through correctly, you'll need to post your output in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), **clearly** showcasing exactly where you want the text to go. The above code will get you the values out of your database, which is what you initially asked for.